# Rebinning multidimensional Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, binning

I have a Python dataframe that looks like this:

```
      0   1       2    3   4    5
0     1   1      10  0.0   6  0.0
1     1   1      20  0.0   3  0.0
2     1   1      30  0.0   6  0.0
3     1   1      40  0.0   2  0.0
4     1   1      50  0.0   5  0.0
5     1   1      60  0.0   6  0.0
6     1   1      70  0.0   3  0.0
7     1   1      80  0.0   6  0.0
8     1   1      90  0.0   2  0.0
9     1   1     100  0.0   4  0.0
10    1   1     110  0.0   4  0.0
11    1   1     120  0.0   3  0.0
12    1   1     130  0.0   6  0.0
13    1   1     140  0.0   5  0.0
14    1   1     150  0.0   5  0.0
15    1   1     160  0.0   2  0.0
16    1   1     170  0.0   2  0.0
17    1   1     180  0.0   1  0.0
18    1   1     190  0.0   1  0.0
19    1   1     200  0.0   6  0.0
..   ..  ..      ..  ...   ..  ..
n-10 99  99     110  0.0   4  0.0     
n-8  99  99     120  0.0   2  0.0
n-7  99  99     130  0.0   9  0.0
n-6  99  99     140  0.0   8  0.0
n-5  99  99     150  0.0   5  0.0 
n-4  99  99     160  0.0   1  0.0
n-3  99  99     170  0.0   0  0.0
n-2  99  99     180  0.0   7  0.0
n-1  99  99     190  0.0   6  0.0
n    99  99     200  0.0   4  0.0
```

And I need to sum my column 4 for every x amount of column 2, where x=10 here.
The output would look like this:

```
      0   1       2    3   4    5
0     1   1     100  0.0  43  0.0
1     1   1     200  0.0  35  0.0
..   ..  ..      ..  ...  ..  ..
m    99  99     200  0.0  46  0.0
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Take the sum of every N rows in a pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239332/take-the-sum-of-every-n-rows-in-a-pandas-series)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69354519/pandas-groupby-bin-and-average

Answers this for me!